# Cannot print a specific number from a sublist within a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to be able to print the 3rd number with in a list of sublist. I am okay with interacting through the list and sublist, but unsure with how i can print the 3rd number of each sublist. 
for example `[[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4][,1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]]` i was to achieve `3,3,3,3`

I have manage this so far, being able to print out all numbers with the sublists

```
def Contact(num):<br/>
    for i in range(len(num)):<br/>
        for j in range(len(num[i])):<br/>
                print(num[i][j])

Contact([[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4][,1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]])
```

Comment: Same as you have, but instead of an inner loop just print the 3rd element: for sublist in list: print sublist[2]

Comment: you are missing a comma between the first, and second and third sublists

Comment: @JacobH Ahh so simple, that makes sense. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

```
def contact(num):
    for sub_list in num:
        print sub_list[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this here http://pythonfiddle.com/

```
def Contact( mainlist ):
    for sublist in mainlist:
        print( sublist[2] ) # accessing third element

Contact( [ [ 1,2,3,4 ], [ 1,2,3,4 ], [ 1,2,3,4 ], [ 1,2,3,4 ] ] )
```